# Laravel 5.8: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. when trying to login

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

My Project was working fine until yesterday, then now when I try to login  I get.

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

This is my login controller

```
 use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function redirectTo()
            {
                if(Auth::user()->admin==0)
                {
                    return '/User_Dashboard';
                }
        
                if(Auth::user()->admin==1 )
                {
                    return '/Admin_Dashboard';
                }
        
                if(Auth::user()->admin==2)
                {
                    return '/Super_Dashboard';
                }
                
            }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request){
        $this->guard()->logout();
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
  
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
    }
```

And this is my Verification controller. I think there is no problem here.

```
  use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->admin==0)
        {
            return '/User_Dashboard';
        }

        if(Auth::user()->admin==1 )
        {
            return '/Admin_Dashboard';
        }

        if(Auth::user()->admin==2)
        {
            return '/Super_Dashboard';
        }
        
    }
```

Last but not least, my web.php

```
    Route::get('/', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');

    Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');

    Route::get('bar-chart', 'ChartsController@index');
 Route::group(['middleware' =>['admin']], function(){

                // Admin Dashboard
        Route::post('/Admin_Dashboard',['uses' =>'DashboardController@adminDashboard', 'as' => 'dashboard']); 
}


 Route::group(['middleware' =>['superAdmin']], function(){

            Route::get('/Super_Dashboard', ['uses'=>'DashboardController@superDashboard', 'as' => 'superUserDashboard']);
}


    Route::get('/User_Dashboard', 'DashboardController@mydashboard')->name('userDashboard');
```

Any problems you see?
I don't remember what changes I made last and now this happened, am kinda new to laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your Super_Dashboard and User_Dashboard routes are get routes? Maybe try changing them to any to see if that works and go from there.

Comment: That should have been my first guess, thanks a lot man.